# jquery ajax search results output

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, http

I am having problem when I search for something and pressed search button it not showing the output.How should I get the results when jquery ajax search results. I am using inteilj

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>mainpage</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input id="mysearch"text="text"  placeholder="Search...">
    <button id="search" >Search </button>
</form>
<ul id="movies">
    <li id="result"></li>
</ul>
<script type="application/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').onkeypress(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/movies',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(index, val){
                        $('#movies').append($('<li>').text('title: ' + val.title + ', year: ' + val.year  ));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably want to use the `.click` event on search. Then see if the `data` received in `success` is correct.

Comment: example it didn't work

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` inside the `success` function show?

Answer (score 0):

use **onClick** event listener so that you script becomes

```
<script type="application/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').on('click',function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/movies',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(index, val){
                        $('#movies').append($('<li>').text('title: ' + val.title + ', year: ' + val.year  ));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I implemented your code but it does not show the results in <li id="result"></li> or <div id="result"></div>

Comment: just above $.each you can add  "alert (am in success)" to see if success function is being executed

Comment: on $(document) or $(#search)

Comment: on  $(#search) inside function(data)

Answer (score 0):

your event should be `.keypress` not `.onkeypress`